Can multiary compositions of elementary functions have an elementary inverse?
I'm looking for general methods for solving equations of elementary functions of one variable in closed form.
Definition:
The elementary functions are generated by applying finite numbers of $\text{exp}$, $\ln$ and/or unary or multiary $\mathbb{C}$-algebraic functions (according to Ritt 1925 and Risch 1979).
An elementary function is called elementary invertible iff it is bijective and its inverse is an elementary function.
Let
$f_1,f_2$ $\mathbb{C}$-algebraically independent elementary invertible elementary functions in the complex numbers and
$P(X_1,X_2)\in\mathbb{C}[X_1,X_2]\setminus\mathbb{C}[X_1]\setminus\mathbb{C}[X_2]$ $\mathbb{C}$-irreducible
so that the function $F\colon D\text{ open }\subseteq\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C},z\mapsto P(f_1(z),f_2(z))$ is bijective and invertible.
My question is:
Are there examples of elementary functions $P,f_1,f_2$ so that we can solve the equation
$\boldsymbol{P(f_1(z),f_2(z))=0}\tag{1}$
for $z$ by applying the elementary inverse function of $F$?
We know Lambert W is inverse relation of functions $z\mapsto ze^z$, but the branches of Lambert W aren't elementary.
The theorem in [Lin 1983] states that equation (1) doesn't have solutions except $0$ in the elementary numbers for $f_1(z)=z,f_2(z)=e^z$. Setting $z\to\ln(z)$ implies this also for $f_1(z)=\ln(z),f_2(z)=z$. It follows that the inverse function of $F$ isn't elementary in these two cases.
And also in the general case, I assume there is no elementary inverse function of $F$, but cannot prove that.
$\ $
[Lin 1983] Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50
